# Best way to change "inner content"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I have [image: this] this layout and I'm planning on using javascript/jquery to change the content in lower box depending on what link is active on the upper.

Before I choose how to do this I would like some inputs on what the best practice is. Im novice when it comes to changing html content using javascript. Specially if you want to factor in doing it in the most resource efficient way.

The layout in the lower box will be different from one another. So each lowerbox layout must be present in the html from the beginning? And each layout should be contained in a div element for easiest way to change the whole block. Am I thinking correctly here?

What jQuery functions should I utilize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ofahib/3/edit)*

Wrap all your DIVs *.page* inside a common container `#pages`:

```
<ul id="navigation">
   <li>Link 1</li>
   <li>Link 2</li>
   <li>Link 3</li>
   <li>Link 4</li>
   <li>Link 5</li>
</ul>
<div id="pages">
   <div class="page">Page 1</div>
   <div class="page">Page 2</div>
   <div class="page">Page 3</div>
   <div class="page">Page 4</div>
   <div class="page">Page 5</div>
</div>
```

Than just  retrieve the index of the clicked navigation and make visible the `.page` with a same index:

```
jQuery(function($){
    
   $('.page:gt(0)').hide(); // hide all pages but first

   $('ul#navigation li').click(function(){
      var liIndex = $(this).index();
      $('.page').hide().eq(liIndex).show(); // hide all and show matching page!
   });


});
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But one thing I noticed is that the e.stopPropagation() function did not prevent the browser from changing site after a few moments after click. I just removed the url in href and its changing fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently been doing something similar.  My advice would be to use jQuery UI's tabs feature.  Each section on your page is a seperate DIV tag which you hide and show as needed.  This will result in the whole page being loaded and available as soon as you press the buttons.

Go here to read more about jQuery UI tabs: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Answer (score 1):

If they must all be in the original HMTL page, then just put each block of content in it's own div, each with it's own id value and each with a common class name, and hide them all by default via CSS with `display: none` and then use javascript to show just the desired set of content based on a click.  On each click, you can hide all of them and show the one you want to display.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap itself has [tabs support](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs), you just need to get over included CSS style for such component in order to preserve yours.

Comment: Yes I noticed. But want to use the built js as little as possible. Use bootstrap for CSS mostly. Thanks though!